# Make A HTML/PHP Link

Tags: php, mysql, html, hyperlink

I have the code below:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT link, notes FROM links WHERE username='will';");
$html .= "<ul>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { //loop
  extract($row);
  $html .= "<li>{$link} - {$notes}</li>";
  }
```

I need the bit where it says `{$link}` to become a clickable link which opens a new window. How would I do this?

When I put  tags around it you get this error:

The error is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /data/www/vhosts/themacsplash.com/httpdocs/ClipBoy/will.php on line 18

Line 18 is `$html .= "<li>{$link} - {$notes}</li>";`

Comment: is it you who wrote it, or you're just seeing it for the first time?

Comment: do you have basic HTML understanding? Why can't you just add appropriate tag to the existing HTML on this page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you make a link like this: `<a href="URL">link title</a>`. So in your case like this:

```
$html .= "<li><a href=\"{$link}\" target=\"_blank\">{$link}</a> - {$notes}</li>";
```

Comment: I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /data/www/vhosts/themacsplash.com/httpdocs/ClipBoy/will.php on line 18

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't escape the quotes. Updated the code. (Can't believe I didn't notice that...)

Answer (score 0):

if your $link contains an url in the form "http://www.example.com/", use this:

```
$html .= "<li><a href=\"{$link}\">{$notes}</a></li>";
```

Comment: doesn't work error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /data/www/vhosts/themacsplash.com/httpdocs/ClipBoy/will.php on line 18

Comment: I just fixed my code by escaping the inner quotes. Sorry about that syntax error

Answer (score 0):

First create a correct code and make error handeling, than set variables outside quotes.

```
$qry = "SELECT link, notes FROM links WHERE username='will'";
$mysqlqry = mysql_query($qry);
if($mysqlqry){
    if(mysql_num_rows($mysqlqry) > 0){

        $html .= "<ul>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { //loop
          extract($row);
          $html .= "<li><a href=". htmlentities($link) .">". $notes ."</a></li>";
        }
    }
}
```